# How to check a value before inserting it in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a bunch of nchar(1) fields that manage integer values.

This is for historical reasons and it is too hard to change them to integer fields (too many ETL procedures will fail since there are many copies of the DB outside).

I would like to avoid the insertion of '' in this table, somehow to simulate an integer field.

somehow it should be "allowed values" are only '1', '2', '3', '4'.

How to perform this with a constraint in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alter table YourTable 
    add constraint CHK_YourTableCol1 
        check (col1 in ('1','2','3','4'));
```